# Stored Procedure Fast in Oracle SQLdeveloper, But Slow in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, stored-procedures

I have several stored procedures, doing a simple insert or update, that runs almost instantly when ran from Oracle SQLdeveloper, but when calling the same stored procedures from a Spring Boot application, it can take about 2 seconds or more.

What could my issue be within my Spring Boot application, causing it to run so much slower than when called by Oracle SQLdeveloper?

Using ojdbc11-production.

Example below of a stored procedure.

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY EXAMPLE_PACKAGE AS

CURSOR c_readexisting(i_id NUMBER)                      
        RETURN EXAMPLE%ROWTYPE is                       
        SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE                       
        where id = i_id             
        for update;

PROCEDURE saveOrUpdate(
    i_id NUMBER,
    i_name varchar2,
    i_numbertest BINARY_DOUBLE,
    i_prompted NUMBER,
    i_captured NUMBER,
    out_id OUT number) is
      v_new EXAMPLE%ROWTYPE;
      v_existing EXAMPLE%ROWTYPE;

    BEGIN

    open c_readexisting (i_id);                     
      fetch c_readexisting into v_existing;                             

    if c_readexisting%notfound then

        v_new.id := HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE.nextval;
        v_new.version := 0;
        v_new.name := i_name;
        v_new.numbertest := i_numbertest;
        v_new.prompted := i_prompted;
        v_new.captured := i_captured;

      insert into EXAMPLE values v_new;

      out_id := v_new.id;

      close c_readexisting;

    else

      v_existing.version := v_existing.version + 1;
      v_existing.name := i_name;
      v_existing.numbertest := i_numbertest;
      v_existing.prompted := i_prompted;
      v_existing.captured := i_captured;

      update EXAMPLE set row = v_existing where id = v_existing.id;

      out_id := v_existing.id;

      close c_readexisting;                     

    end if;

    EXCEPTION                       

      WHEN OTHERS THEN                      

        IF c_readexisting%ISOPEN THEN                       
          CLOSE c_readexisting;                     
        END IF;                     
          dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);                        
        RAISE;  

    END;

END EXAMPLE_PACKAGE;
```

Current datasource in my application.yml

```
datasource:
    url: URL
    username: USER
    password: PASSWORD
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    type: oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource
    oracleucp:
      connection-factory-class-name: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
      min-pool-size: 20
      max-pool-size: 20
      max-idle-time: 300000
      initial-pool-size: 20
      fast-connection-failover-enabled: true
```

And Repository class.

```
@Repository
public class ExampleRepository {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public ExampleRepository(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
    } 
 
    public Long saveOrUpdate(Example example) {

            SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                .withCatalogName("EXAMPLE_PACKAGE")
                .withProcedureName("saveOrUpdate");

            SqlParameterSource mapSqlParameter = new MapSqlParameterSource(example.getMapForProcedure());
            
            Map<String, Object> out = simpleJdbcCall.execute(mapSqlParameter);

            var stopId = (BigDecimal)out.get("out_id");

            return stopId.longValue();

    }
}
```

Comment: How to you compare the execution time? Are you sure you don't include the connection time when measuring the Spring version?

Comment: @p3consulting I am simply using Spring StopWatch to see how long it takes to run saveOrUpdate in ExampleRepository. I am also running it a few times, to ensure the app has already made a connection. It gets triggered from an API call, so I am not including the time it takes to start up the app. And maybe this is where I am confused, but I thought by setting the connection pool, that it would hold the connection. Please let me know if this is not the case and if I am missing something

Comment: Some connection pool managers wont setup the pool until you make the first call, so perhaps measure first, second, etc calls to see if connection is indeed playing a part.

Comment: Also, I know its just sample code, but if the "check if exists, then insert or update" template is truly representative of your code, then be aware that your code is still at risk if two or more instances of the program both run the code with a non-existent value. They'll both see "no existing row" and both insert the same non-PK values, each one now having a new sequence ID.

Comment: Also, "set row" for an update (whilst convenient) will also set the PK columns to itself, which has implications if your table is a parent table in a parent-child foreign key.  You might consider looking at a MERGE command to make the routine a LOT smaller

Comment: And if you can eliminate connection time (and its still slow), throw a sql trace on the executions. It might be the driver doing something querying the dictionary to validate the stored proc parameters etc

Comment: Which jdk you use with your SQL Developer? Maybe it differs from SpringBoot ojdbc11?